# Is there a better way to write this code in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know I can apply switch-case operators but I think still looks a little bit verbose. Basically is a list of dynamic values wrapped in a Widget, and returns a BaseItemWidget to a ListView.

Here is the list:

```
class MyListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      onReorder: provider.reorderList,
      children: provider.items.map((item) {
        return Dismissible(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          direction: DismissDirection.none,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              BaseItemWidget(item),
              const Divider(height: 0)
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the widget inside that list:

```
class BaseItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final dynamic item;

  const BaseItemWidget({Key? key, this.item}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (item is TextItem) {
      return TextItemWidget(item);
    } else if (item is EditableItem) {
      return EditableItemWidget(item);
    } else if (item is ImageItem) {
      return ImageItemWidget(item);
    } else if (item is BarcodeItem) {
      return BarcodeItemWidget(item);
    }
    return const SpaceItemWidget();
  }
}
```

The item inside all that widgets it's also dynamic.

Comment: How different are the widgets from each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider having each of your `XItem` classes extend an abstract `BaseItem` class, which has a `widget` method which constructs the right widget for the item. Something like this:

```dart
abstract class BaseItem {
  Widget widget();
}

class TextItem extends BaseItem {
  @override
  Widget widget() => TextItemWidget(this);
}

// Etc, for the other item types

class MyListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      onReorder: provider.reorderList,
      children: provider.items.map((item) {
        return Dismissible(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          direction: DismissDirection.none,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              item.widget(),
              const Divider(height: 0)
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!, I used to do a similar thing in kotlin, but I didn't know how to apply it with Flutter

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Michael Horn for the answer, here is the result:

```
class TextItem extends BaseItemWidget{
  TextAlign align;
  TicketLineColor color;
  double size;
  String text;
  bool isBold;
  bool isUnderlined;

  TextItem({
    this.size = 20,
    this.text = '',
    this.isBold = false,
    this.isUnderlined = false,
    this.align = TextAlign.left,
    this.color = TicketLineColor.black,
  });

  PosText toPosText() {
    final posText = PosText(
      text: text,
      isBold: isBold,
      isUnderlined: isUnderlined,
      posAlign: align.toPosAlign(),
      posColor: color.toPosColor(),
    );
    return posText;
  }

  String generatePosString() => toPosText().toString();

  @override
  Widget widget() => TextItemWidget(this);
}
```